# Send WhatsApp message automatically

Tags: java, android, whatsapp

Trying to send WhatsApp message automatically.  I have a pre-filled message in the code, that will automatically appear in the text field of a whatsapp chat, but the user needs to click the send button.  Is there any way to send the message automatically (without the need to click the button)?

```
sendmessage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Intent intent = new Intent();    
        intent.setData(Uri.parse(
            "https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone="
            + ccp.getFullNumberWithPlus() + enternumber.getText()
            + "&text=" +msg.getText()
        ));
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

Comment: I think this is not working intentionally

Comment: No, WhatsApp doesn't provide such features. Mostly because of potential Spam and security reasons. Even Android canceled some SMS features because of the reasons mentioned above. Many Apps where removed from the PlayStore 2 years ago.

Comment: It's not possible. It would be abused by scammers if it was. It would essentially allow anyone to get your WhatsApp to message anyone else without confirmation revealing your phone number.

Comment: But there is a whatsapp reminder app.How it is possible in that app? @davidev @

Comment: @JithinMSs They are sending messages from your Account or you receive messages from them?

Comment: They are sending messages from my account @davidev

Answer (score 1):

just use

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
```

and then your message variable to write the message

the code to write the message: `.send_keys("message")` /you could also send the message variable

the code to send the message/press enter: `.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)`